# Is there a standard name for a set which can be written as a countable union of compact sets?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

The question is all in the title... Is there a standard name for a set which can be written as a countable union of compact sets? I guess it might be a $\sigma$-compact set, in analogy with the topological spaces, but I've never heard this name referred to a set. Is it actually the standard choice? Is there any better alternative?

Comment: You make a distinction between sets and topological spaces. What are compact sets, of you don't have a topology?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I think the difference is between a topological space considered on its own, versus a subset of a given topological space. A priori this isn't a silly distinction to make, although in this particular case it winds up being vacuous per my answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am aware of the distinction, I just have a hard time imagining a case where this comes handy. Either we pick the subspace topology on the subsets or we allow any topology on the subsets and suddenly every set is the union of countably many compact subsets.

Comment: @NoahSchweber My last comment reads a bit aggressive (which was not my intention) and of course I agree with both your comment and your answer. All I wanted to say is that the OP might want to clarify his definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've definitely seen "$\sigma$-compact" used for subsets of a given space as well as spaces on their own, and I believe it is indeed the standard term in this context.

Note that if $\mathcal{X}=(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and $A\subseteq X$, the following are equivalent: $(i)$ $A$ is a union of countably many compact sets in $\mathcal{X}$, and $(ii)$ the subspace $\mathcal{A}=(A,\tau_A)$ is a $\sigma$-compact space. This justifies the use of the term "$\sigma$-compact" in *both* senses.

Comment: $\sigma$-compact is the established term, see Engelking, Kelley etc.